# What tool is available for managing the P410i raid controller?

Tags: linux, raid, hp

I have a HP server with a HP P410i raid controller installed.  From linux (centos 7 at the moment), how can I manage the raid controller from the OS (not from the BIOS, please)?  For example, I'm looking for a command line utility to examine and modify raid configuration and the disks connected to it.  Tasks would include: configure a new disk as JBOD, examine smart data, add / remove drives from existing raid configurations, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need the HPE system management agents. Or specifically, you can get by with the hpssa and hpssacli utilities. The latter is the command line management tool. These are available as RPMs.

That’s all that’s required.

As a note, there is no JBOD capability on the P410. That is available in the P420 and later controller models.

Comment: Where does one get hpssacli?  HP does not make it easy to find this stuff.

Comment: Found it.  Package repository information here: https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/ and https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/spp/

Comment: Regarding JBOD capability, would not switching to HBA mode with [`hpsahba -E DEVICE_PATH`](https://github.com/im-0/hpsahba) provide that? (and P410i is specifically given as an example)